# Is it correct to say "Don't YOU cry" instead of "Don't cry"?

Tags: pronouns, imperative-sentences

Is it correct to say "Don't **YOU** cry" instead of "Don't cry". I mean that I know that usually people you the second form (don't cry) but my question if there are cases that the first form (Don't **YOU** cry) is correct.

Comment: Because it is in all caps and boldfaced, it makes me think that it is stressed as it is said.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. "[Don't **you** cry tonight, there's a heaven above you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRIbf6JqkNc)" - from an old Guns'n'Roses song.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. The imperative does not usually have a subject, but we can use a noun or a pronoun to make it clear who we are speaking to. "You" is emphatic in this case.

> - You take your hands off me!
> - Don't you believe it!

Comment: It's not wrong, but I think it has a slightly colloquial, maybe patronizing connotation.  I wouldn't use it in formal speech or writing.